# Validate fields of Signature Pad only when Radio Button is selected

Tags: jquery

I need some help

I'm using [Signature-Pad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/) in a Form with 2 Radio Buttons for selecting the payment method: CreditCard and Electronic Check with Signature Pad.
How can I validate Signature Pad value only when it was selected "Electronic Check"?

I tryied smth like that but its not working.

```
$(".payment-chek").click(function () {
if($(this).closest("table").parent().hasClass("altcharge_processing")) {
$(".sigPad").signaturePad({drawOnly:true});  //selected Electronic Check
} else {
$.fn.signaturePad.validateFields = false;  //selected CreditCard
}
});
```